# adding a key to other users in the registry using admin account programmatically

Tags: c#, c++, c, windows, registry

How do I add a new key in the registry of other users using c# (or c/c++ or other language)

here is the scenario:
Client PC: "Administrator" account(logged in)

"User A" and "User B" can login on the Client PC only through a domain "myDomain" (they have already logged on once and have their own folder in user of the Client PC)

so I will run this code to create a new key using administrator

> Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\myProgram\DefaultConfig");

but the problem is, this key is only created for the "Administrator" account

I want to create this key for "User A" and "User B" too while still using "Administrator" account

both "User A" and "User B" does not appear in the HKEY_USERS

And is if there are more users in the same PC I want to add this registry key to them also is it possible to loop a code that adds a key for all users? Read and write loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keys for all users are stored under the `HKEY_USERS` root key. Under this root key, there is a key for every user which has its [SID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Identifier) as key name.

You'll have to get the SID of the desired user, then access to this root key:

```
// Gets the SID of the desired user
NTAccount f = new NTAccount(userName);
SecurityIdentifier s = (SecurityIdentifier)f.Translate(typeof(SecurityIdentifier));
string sid = s.ToString();

// Now you can access to the HKEY_USERS root key
string path = @"SOFTWARE\Console\DefaultConfig";
Registry.Users.CreateSubKey(string.Format("{0}\\{1}", sid, path));
```

But honestly, I'm not sure it's a very good idea. Couldn't you use `Registry.LocalMachine` instead, which applies to all users?

Comment: Their hives are only loaded if they are currently logged in.  It would be better to create the key the first time that user runs the program.

Comment: Isn't it likely that OP is trying to do something malicious? Adding/changing registry keys for all users (rather than, as Luke said, just doing it the first time they run the program, or using a system-wide setting) sounds like you're trying to do make a change that's intentionally hard to clean out/reverse...

Comment: I'm trying to put a config on all users, I did not actually make the program(the myProgram name is just for example purpose) so I can't do anything about putting an auto config on start, and I'm going to config several computers, thanks for the code, but one more question, why is it that I can't edit the registry of other users when they are not logged in?

Comment: oops I just read the 1st comment sorry for redundant post, is it not possible to edit their registry/"hives" when they are not logged in?

Comment: It is possible, but not advisable.  First of all, if that user tries to login while you've got their registry hive loaded they will be unable to load their hive and get a temp copy of the default user hive (bad experience).  Secondly, you can cause problems with roaming profiles (e.g. data loss).

Comment: i know this is a really old question but this came to my mind too so.. is it advisable not to remove application relevant keys on each user when i intend to do a clean uninstall of my application?

Comment: nevermind. got it working just fine using `Registry.Users.GetSubKeyNames()` and `true` as second param in `OpenSubKey()` and in addition i even clean up empty keys cause i care about clean uninstall routines :D